# Proof verifications for set equality

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Can I get a proof verification? Are there any flaws in this proof? The examples in the book are only for sets bounded either above or below.

Prove $$\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{n}{n+1})=(0,1)$$

Assume $x \in \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{n}{n+1})$.

Thus $\exists n_x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$x \in (0,\frac{n_x}{n_x+1})$

$\implies 0<x<\frac{n_x}{n_x+1}$

also since $0<1 \implies$

$n_x<n_x+1 \implies \frac{n_x}{n_x+1}<1$

We have

$0<x<\frac{n_x}{n_x+1}<1$

Thus $x \in (0,1)$

So $$\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{n}{n+1})\subseteq(0,1)$$

Assume $0<x<1$

Then since $0<1-x$,$\frac{x}{1-x} \in \mathbb{R}$

By the Archimedean property $\exists n \in 
\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>\frac{x}{1-x}$

Thus $0<x< \frac{n}{n+1}$

So $x \in \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{n}{n+1})$

And $$\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(0,\frac{n}{n+1})\supseteq(0,1)$$

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: For  part 1 you can simply observe that the set is the union of some subsets of (0,1) and therefore it must be a subset of (0,1) too. Good work.